# Need help for adding border on dotted line shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, shader

I've got a script in Unity for dotted line shader like in 
[that example](https://www.facebook.com/Dvionst/videos/1941314302559254/)

The problem is I want to make a black border around each circle and I'm new in using shaders. Anyone can help me or teach me? Here is the script, in case anyone needs it:

```
Shader "Unlit/DottedLineShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _RepeatCount("Repeat Count", float) = 5
        _Spacing("Spacing", float) = 0.5
        _Offset("Offset", float) = 0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags{ "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Transparent" }
        LOD 100

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ZWrite Off

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            float _RepeatCount;
            float _Spacing;
            float _Offset;

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                fixed4 color : COLOR0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color : COLOR0;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.uv.x = (o.uv.x + _Offset) * _RepeatCount * (1.0f + _Spacing);
                o.color = v.color;

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                i.uv.x = fmod(i.uv.x, 1.0f + _Spacing);
                float r = length(i.uv - float2(1.0f + _Spacing, 1.0f) * 0.5f) * 2.0f;

                fixed4 color = i.color;
                color.a *= saturate((0.99f - r) * 100.0f);

                return color;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in smoothstep function to "clip" part of radius (r) and create a pixel perfect, anti-aliased border;

```
// Values below must be between 0-1
float borderRadius = 0.5;
float borderSmoothness = 0.1;    

color.rgb *= smoothstep(borderRadius - borderSmoothness, borderRadius, 1.0 - r);
```

Comment: Youre awesome bro! It works! Thx very much

Here is the current script for anyone who needed it
https://pastebin.com/YUMM2XH4